# WCF JSONP returns blank/empty document when NULL is returned

Tags: .net, wcf, null, jsonp

I am using the JSONP samples provided by Microsoft.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898(v=vs.90).aspx

JSONPEncoderFactory
JSONPBindingExtension
JSONPBindingElement
JSONPBehavior

Everything works fine, except when returning null.
Instead of what I want, which is:  callback(null);
It returns a blank document which causes an error with most JSONP frameworks like

```
jQuery.ajax({jsonp:"callback"});
```

I put breakpoints on every method call in the custom classes and the one that does all the work:

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
```

The closest I've came to finding a solution is mere speculation. I thought that maybe the WebServiceHost class might have a method I can override to build in the functionality I am expecting, but so far I have come up empty handed.

I wanted to also mention I am not using the WebScriptServiceHostFactory class because of the following issue:

```
Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.
```

If I use this factory, returning null causes the functionality I am looking for. However, then I cannot use TemplateUri's, and I am using those for the HMAC encryption. Since I cannot use headers in JSONP requests are formatted as

```
/Service/Action/publicKey-signature?params
```

I tried finding a standard for HMAC over a JSONP type request but couldn't find anything. This was the cleanest I could come up with. Params is used as the signature.

**UPDATE:**

The things I were missing when attempting the below solution were you have to make sure that on your web.config you build a webHttpBinding that has crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true". Also you have to make sure to **not** use the  behavior. Also do not use the WebScriptServiceHostFactory.
You can use the WebServiceHostFactory, but then you must have this in a web.config (or do it for the single service through binding):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you using the .NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0? With 4.0, JSONP support is built-in the classes, so you don't need to have the encoder as shown in the sample.

Comment: I am using 4.0. I explain what happens when you try to use JSONP with the built-in classes. You cannot use TemplateUri. Unless you have a way to allow for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4.0 framework has native JSONP support, and it does support URI templates, as shown in the example below. You'll need to enable the support on the `WebHttpBinding` class (or in config, if you prefer).

```
public class StackOverflow_7974435
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Sum?x={x}&y={y}")]
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Data?isNull={isNull}")]
        public string GetData(bool isNull)
        {
            return isNull ? null : "Hello world";
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding { CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true };
        WebHttpBehavior behavior = new WebHttpBehavior { DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json };
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service), binding, "").Behaviors.Add(behavior);
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Not a JSONP call");
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Sum?x=6&y=8"));

        Console.WriteLine("A JSONP call");
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Sum?x=6&y=8&callback=MyFunction"));

        Console.WriteLine("A JSONP call returning string");
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Data?isNull=false&callback=MyFunction"));

        Console.WriteLine("A JSONP call returning null");
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Data?isNull=true&callback=MyFunction"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

**Update**: added also another operation which returns null, and the calls to it. In the first call (returning string), the service returns `MyFunction("Hello world");`, while in the second case it correctly returns `MyFunction(null);`. As I mentioned in the comments, if you're not using the ASP.NET AJAX framework, do not use the `WebScriptEnablingBehavior`, as it's not meant to be used for other frameworks.

Comment: Are you using a factory on the service?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.

Comment: If I take off the factory I just get 400 bad request

Comment: Even the sample from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx Errors when you try to use UriTemplate.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinjsmith/archive/2008/02/15/enablewebscript-uritemplate-and-http-methods.aspx "Then, instead of using the enableWebScript behavior, use the WebHttpBehavior. You'll lose compat with the ASP.NET AJAX client stack (and the JS proxy), but you have the URI you are looking for."

Comment: This code doesn't use a factory, but you can create your own factory to do that (see some information at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx). The code doesn't use the `WebScriptEnablingBehavior` (or `<enableWebScript/>` if in config), it uses the general-purpose `WebHttpBehavior`. Since you're using jQuery.ajax, **do not use WebScriptEnablingBehavior** (it's for compat with the "ASP.NET AJAX" framework only. Use the other one.

Comment: When you do this, it does not support returning null, which is what my question is about. If you try returning null, the response is blank. If you use the WebScript behavior, it properly returns null.

Comment: I updated the example - it does work correctly when returning null.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... it returns a blank document, with no callback. Just... a complete and absolute blank document.

Comment: Are you running the exact code I have in the answer, or your JS code calling the service? If the latter, can you look at a network monitor (such as Fiddler) and post here the exact URL used by the request.

Comment: I am using a network proxy. I checked fiddler, and firefox firebug network window. I'll try running it again today.

Comment: host.Open -> Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. 

I tried running your solution within a WCF Service Application project. I added a .aspx file and put your code within it, and it stops debugging every time it runs. I run the page, then the processes crash with no errors.

Comment: I got the example to work WITHOUT using the webclient to invoke it, just using a browser or fiddler. I added ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json. In web.config I use webHttp behavior, and a "webHttpBinding". When I invoke the NULL I get a completely blank document. If I could attach a screenshot of fiddler I would.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4729/discussion-between-bradlaney-and-carlosfigueira)